# Cryptic error in lxml when opening file

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, error-handling, lxml

My code is rather simple;

```
f = open(r"C:\filepath\file.xml")
xml = f.read()
tree = etree.parse(xml)
```

When running this, I get the stack trace

```
tree = etree.parse(xml)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:79801)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1782, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:115995)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1808, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:116345)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1712, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:115233)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1115, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:109930)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 573, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103404)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105058)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 611, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103924)
IOError
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse()` accepts path to the XML file :

```
tree = etree.parse(r"C:\filepath\file.xml")
```

Currently your code passes actual content of the XML to `parse()`, which will trigger such `IOError`. You can use `fromstring()` instead to create `Element` object from a string containing the actual XML data. And if needed, you can then create an `ElementTree` object from previously created `Element` :

```
f = open(r"C:\filepath\file.xml")
xml = f.read()
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
```